# How does LinkedIn Throttling count my calls?

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api, throttling

I've been using LinkedIn API in my application and I noticed that the call count for profile requests in LinkedIn dashboard is significantly higher than the amount of calls I'm doing (something like 10 times the amount of calls I've been doing).

I'm using bulk calls and field selectors.

Did anyone else have such experience? Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Throttle Limits documentation](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits):

> Note: Bulk requests are throttled as if you make multiple individual requests, so they provide efficiency, not extra information.

So each part of your bulk requests counts as one request.

But without knowing what *exactly* you are doing, there's no chance to say if this really is the reason for what you experience.

Comment: I know that bulk requests are throttled as multiple individual ones, but this does not explain the numbers I've been getting. The numbers I've been getting are about 10 times higher also when taking that into account. Do you know if the use of field selectors may be related?

Comment: Ah sorry, that was not clear to me from your question. Field selectors should make no difference, as according to a [response](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/15942#comment-15942) in LinkedIn's forums, only the number of objects you get returned from a bulk request should increase the count.